# How to get CDF from given function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I get this function

> $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
>          \frac{0}{3} ,&\text{$|x|\geq 2$}\\
>          \frac{1}{3}, &\text{$|x|\leq 1$}\\
>          \frac{2-|x|}{3},& \text{$1\le|x|\leq2$}\\
>        \end{cases}$$

I need to convert in CDF but I do not know how I get som part of solution, I know how function look,I know that for $x\le-2$ I get $F(x)=0$, now I know how to get $-2<x\le-1$, $\int_{-2}^{x}\frac{2+x}{3}=\frac{(x+2)^2}{6}$, I think that for $1<x\le2$ is not good I get  $\int_{1}^{x}\frac{2-x}{3}=\frac{-x^2+4x-3}{6}$, but for $-1<x\le1$, I have no idea how he get that, can you help me?

This is solution that I get in book

> $$F(x) = \begin{cases}
>          0 , & \text{$x\le-2$}\\
>          \frac{(x+2)^2}{6}, &\text{$-2<x\le-1$}\\
>          \frac{2x+3}{6}, &\text{$-1<x\le1$}\\
>           \frac{-x^2+4x+2}{6},& \text{ $1<x\le2$}\\
>            1, &\text{$x>2$}
>        \end{cases}$$

Comment: I have editted can you please recheck if this is your question ?

Comment: I do not get anything to recheck, I want, but I do not get that

Comment: The question you wrote had mistakes.. you've copied the question wrong.. I've corrected the mistakes.. could you just verify?

Comment: I know I get how to do it but thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $-1 < x \le 1$ we have

$$F(x) = F(-1) + \int_{-1}^x \frac13 \,dt = \frac{(-1+2)^2}{6} + \frac{x+1}3 = \frac{2x+3}6$$

For $1 < x \le 2$ we have

$$F(x) = F(1) + \int_1^x \frac{2-t}3 = \frac56 + \frac{-x^2+4x-3}6 = \frac{-x^2+4x+2}6$$

Comment: can you just explain me how you get F(-1) and F(1)?

Comment: @MarkoŠkorić For $-1 < x \le 1$ we have
$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(t)\,dt = \int_{-\infty}^{-1} f(t)\,dt + \int_{-1}^x f(t)\,dt  = F(-1) + \int_{-1}^x \frac13\,dt = \cdots$$
You have already calculated that for $-2 < x \le -1$ we have $F(x) = \frac{(x+2)^2}3$ so I just plugged in $x = -1$.

Comment: thank you so much